# How to make a symmetric matrix of symbols in python?

Tags: python, sympy, linear-algebra

I´d like to create a matrix whose elements are all variables, so i tried the following

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy import MatrixSymbol, Matrix

A=sp.symbols('rho0:'+str(side*(side)/2))

rho = MatrixSymbol('rho', side, side)

rho[0][0]=A[0]
count=0
for i in range(side):
  for j in range(i,side):
    rho[i][j]=A[count]
    rho[j][i]=rho[i][j]
    count+=1
```

Nevertheless it seems the type of matrix I´m using doesn´t support symbols, what should I do ?

Comment: It would be clearer if you told us that `rho[0][0]=A[0]` produced the `TypeError: 'MatrixElement' object does not support item assignment`.  Maybe even showed us what `rho[0,0]` is.  `rho` is a `MatrixSymbol`, `rho[0,0]` is a `MatrixElement`.

Answer (score 0):

MatrixSymbol is used to represent an abstract matrix as a single entity/symbol in a manner like Symbol is used to represent a scalar. If you are just going to use generic symbols in order, perhaps you could use

```py
>>> MatrixSymbol('rho', 2, 2).as_explicit()
Matrix([[rho[0, 0], rho[0, 1]], [rho[1, 0], rho[1, 1]]])
```

Notice that a normal Matrix of symbols has been produced.

But since you want the matrix to be symmetric you would either have to loop back over the matrix and assign elements below the matrix as you tried in your code above.

Alternatively, you can modify what you did above by using correct Matrix indexing and a Matrix instead of a MatrixSymbol:

```py
import sympy as sp
from sympy import zeros, Matrix
sides = 2
A=sp.symbols('rho0:'+str(side*(side+1)/2))  # note (side+1) not side

rho = zeros(side, side)

rho[0,0]=A[0]
count=0
for i in range(side):
  for j in range(i,side):
    rho[i,j]=A[count]
    rho[j,i]=rho[i,j]
    count+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you first make a matrix that is not symmetric then you can make a symmetric matrix out of its elements:

```
In [23]: M = MatrixSymbol('M', 3, 3)

In [24]: M
Out[24]: M

In [25]: M.as_explicit()
Out[25]: 
⎡M₀₀  M₀₁  M₀₂⎤
⎢             ⎥
⎢M₁₀  M₁₁  M₁₂⎥
⎢             ⎥
⎣M₂₀  M₂₁  M₂₂⎦

In [26]: M[0,0]
Out[26]: M₀₀

In [27]: Msym = Matrix(3, 3, lambda i, j: M[min(i,j),max(i,j)])

In [28]: Msym
Out[28]: 
⎡M₀₀  M₀₁  M₀₂⎤
⎢             ⎥
⎢M₀₁  M₁₁  M₁₂⎥
⎢             ⎥
⎣M₀₂  M₁₂  M₂₂⎦

In [29]: Msym.is_symmetric()
Out[29]: True
```